# Level Sets of Harmonic Maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, geometric-analysis

Can anybody point me in the direction of some references in which the level sets of harmonic maps between Riemannian manifolds are studied. (Sorry I am unfamiliar with the area and would like some some starting points).